# Right clickup and right clickdown event in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vue 2.1.10.

I am using @contextmenu event to detect on right click events.

But I want to detect right click up and down events.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of v2.2, you can listen for right mouse click events using the [`right` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Mouse-Button-Modifiers) (and prevent the default behavior of the `contextmenu` event by using the [`prevent` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)):

```
<button 
  @mousedown.right="mousedown" 
  @mouseup.right="mouseup" 
  @contextmenu.prevent
>
  Click Me
</button>
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/veydeeju/)

---

If you aren't using v2.2 or above, you can manually check for the right mouse click using the `which` property of the click event instead:

```
<button 
  @mousedown="mousedown" 
  @mouseup="mouseup" 
  @contextmenu.prevent
>
  Click Me
</button>
```

```javascript
methods: {
  mousedown(event) {
    if (event.which === 3) {
      console.log("Right mouse down");        
    }
  },
  mouseup(event) {
    if (event.which === 3) {
      console.log("Right mouse up");
    }
  }
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/veydeeju/2/)

Comment: This event was introduced in vue 2.2. But I am using vue 2.1.10.
So this won't work.